# Opening Windows files with Wine

Tags: windows, wine

I can access my Windows files while running Ubuntu, but can I run for example Skype via Wine without installing it on Ubuntu?
My idea it's just simply run programs, which had been already installed on windows but aren't installed on linux, using wine. Is that possible or I must install those programs on linux too in order to they run correctly?

Comment: @amc I don't think that duplicate applies here. OP is asking if it's possible to use the software in Wine **without** installing it in Ubuntu as well by mounting the Windows partition.

Comment: @gertvdijk the question is clearer now after the edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you need to have a separate instance of the game inside your ubuntu partition.

If you install programs using PlayOnLinux or Winetricks they will automatically put them into the correct folder.